# How to make a reset/refresh button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how I can have a button to refresh the page with resetting all the values to theire defaults values in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <body>
         <button onclick="myFunction()"> Reload page </button>
            <script>
                function myFunction() 
                  {
                      location.reload();
                  }
            </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it is a good and clear answer but do you have any idea of how to reset all the values in the page?

Comment: This one's nice and easy. I'll give you the code. Copy and paste it into the document you wish to reload. Once in there, change the number of seconds you wish the page to wait before starting the reloading process. This code goes in between the HEAD tags.
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">
Right now, the command is set to reload every 15 seconds. I checked a couple of online sites and they were all set about the same. I found the sites displaying stock information were set to around five minutes or 300 seconds